# How to run the .exe file that is made by visual foxpro 6.0 in a different computer?

Tags: desktop-application, visual-foxpro

My brother installed an application (.exe) in my laptop it is working. Now i want to change my laptop and copy all the applications. Out of all application one is 'xyz.exe' which is developed in visual foxpro. And when i simply copy this application into my new laptop it tried to run it shows "Cannot locate the Microsoft Visual FoxPro support library".
I am unable to figure this out.

Answer (score 4):

You will need to install the appropriate VFP runtime libraries on that PC.

Here is a link to a site that contains installs of all the different VFP runtime libraries:

```
http://www.foxpert.com/download/runtime.html
```

Down and install the correct file to fix your problem.